# Matplotlib put x ticks above bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, figure

Is there any way to put the x-ticks above each stacked bar in a stacked bar chart, rather than below the x-axis? To be clear, I don't mean place the x-tick above each individual bar in a single stacked bar, I mean place the x-tick above the stacked bar itself. Here's how I'm creating my plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(3200, 3)))    
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index, size=3190, replace=False), :] = 0

df_select = df[df.sum(axis=1)>1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df_select.index, df_select.iloc[:,0], label = df_select.columns[0], wdith = 15)

if df_select.shape[1] > 1:
    for i in range(1, df_select.shape[1]):
        bottom = df_select.iloc[:,np.arange(0,i,1)].sum(axis=1)
        ax.bar(df_select.index, df_select.iloc[:,i], bottom=bottom, label = 
df_select.columns[i], width = 15)

ax.set_xticks(df_select.index)
plt.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=8) #this puts the x ticks below the x axis
```

Additionally, I'd like to place some text at specific points along the x axis. I'm storing these sites in a list:

```
sites = [19, 173, 1002] # the number and elements of this list vary
```

So, for example, at x = 173, I'd like to place the text 'site (173)' along with a tick at position 173.

For your reference, I've posted images for what my current code produces, and what I would like to produce:
current: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDlEP.png
goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJJo4.png

Comment: Like this? https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Yes but rather than the y val on top of the bar, I'd like to put the x val. I tried using the code in the link already (tweaked to put x val instead of y), but since it's a stacked plot it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you post your updated code? I am not able to get a reasonable looking plot with what you've posted; assuming np, pd, plt imported.

Comment: Try passing width for ax.bar()... the bars seem to be too thin to show up in some cases. width = 15 worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the example that @Evan linked to in this comments, namely [this one](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). The important bit is the function named `autolabel` in the linked example. Changing the values displayed from the y axis values to the x axis values is easy, replace `height` with `rect.get_x()`. The trickier bit is putting the values at the top of the bar. The total height of your bars can be found by summing the values in your DataFrame.

```
heights = df_select.iloc[:,:].sum(axis=1)
```

This then needs to be passed to the autolabel function and used as the height of the bars. The x tick labels can be removed using

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
```

And you can add further text below your x axis for specific sites by simply using `ax.text` using the contents of `sites` as the x location, and setting the y location to be below the axis (-0.5 or something).

Putting this all together, we get the following working example:

```
def autolabel(rects, heights):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    Modified for use with a stacked bar chart
    """
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        x = rect.get_x()
        wid = rect.get_width()
        height = heights.values[i]

        ax.text(x + wid/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % (int(x) + int((wid/2)+0.5)),
                ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(3200, 3)))    
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index, size=3190, replace=False), :] = 0

df_select = df[df.sum(axis=1)>1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df_select.index, df_select.iloc[:,0], label = df_select.columns[0], width = 15)

if df_select.shape[1] > 1:
    for i in range(1, df_select.shape[1]):
        bottom = df_select.iloc[:,np.arange(0,i,1)].sum(axis=1)
        rects1 = ax.bar(df_select.index, df_select.iloc[:,i], bottom=bottom, label = 
df_select.columns[i], width = 15)

ax.set_xticks(df_select.index)
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])   # turn off the x tick labels

plt.legend(loc='best', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

heights = df_select.iloc[:, :].sum(axis=1)
autolabel(rects1, heights)

# Select 3 random value to add labels below the x axis. Make sure they are
# within the axis limits
sites = np.random.choice(df_select.index, 3)

for site in sites:
    ax.text(site, -0.5,
        'site(%s)' % site,
        ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=6)

plt.show()
```

Which gives the following graph:

[image]

**Note:** this can sometimes look messy because the bars are very thin and spread out, and can be placed close to each other, meaning values may start to overlap.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean setting x-tick labels at the top of your figure's frame, try `ax.xaxis.tick_top()` at the bottom of your current code.

To place text labels at custom x-axis locations: based on [these docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html), this should work:

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=8)
sites = [19, 173, 1002]
site_labels = ['label at 19', 'label at 173', 'label at 1002']
new_locs = np.append(locs, sites)
new_labels = np.append(labels, site_labels)
plt.xticks(new_locs, new_labels)
```

Comment: I was hoping to put the x ticks on top of the bars themselves, rather than the top of the figure's frame.

Comment: Do you have any example images of the desired result? Not sure if I've seen x-ticks placed like that before.

Comment: Sure - I added an image to my question.